# move content from div to another automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css

Lets say I have two div's, one called div A and the other one called div B.

Now, div B must have the exact content of div A, so I have to manually copy and paste the content from A to B every time I change the content in A...

Is there a way maybe using CSS to give div B whatever is in div A?

Example:

```
<!--Contact Details Section-->
                    <div id="contactDetails">

                        <div id="contactDetails-normal">
                            <h3>Contact Details</h3>
                            <p><strong>Email:</strong> email@websitename.com</p>
                            <p><strong>Telephone:</strong> 020 8202 9767</p>
                        </div>

                        <!--Phone contact buttons-->
                        <div class="hidden" id="contactDetails-smart">
                            <a href="tel:020 8202 9767">Call us: 020 8202 9767</a>
                                <br>
                            <p><strong>Email:</strong> email@websitename.com</p>
                        </div>
                        <br>
```

So as you can see above, I have two divs, one is contactDetails-normal and contactDetails-smart... each will show on a different size screen. But both will always have the same info...

Comment: You can use Javascript for what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you want to go down this route, you should use a Javascript MVVM framework like Angular, Knockout, etc. Not some repetitive Javascript solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with CSS.

But you can use jquery to do this easily :

```
$(function() {        
    $("#B").html($("#A").html());    
 });
```

This will simply copy all the html code inside the A div to the B div.

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/e9GBn/1/

Comment: @Leo I changed my code, as the txt variable, which was an intermediate, was unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using CSS, you'll need to resort to Javascript if you want this to happen, e.g. in jQuery you could use:

`$( "#div2" ).html($( "#div1" ).html(););`

Alternatively, if you only wish to copy textual content use `text()`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the edits to the question I would recommend using css media query to style one element differently based on screen size instead of having repetitive HTML and extra javascript.

html

```
<div id="contactDetails">
  <h3>Contact Details</h3>
  <p><strong>Email:</strong> email@websitename.com</p>
  <p class="tel"><strong>Telephone:</strong> 0000000</p>
  <p class="sms"><strong>SMS:</strong> 0000000</p>
</div>
```

css

```
#contactDetails {
    //Styling for large screen size
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

  #contactDetails {
      //Styling for screen size smaller than 400px
  }

}
```

If you want elements inside the contactDetails to be visible only on smaller screen sizes you can also address them in the media query like so (note: i have added the relevant classes to the above html.)

css

```
#contactDetails .tel, #contactDetails .sms {
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

  #contactDetails .tel, #contactDetails .sms {
      display:inline;
  }

}
```

If you use this, be careful as older browsers don't always support media queries you may need to use something like respond.js to help them along https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: oh! how I did not think about that!

Comment: I am going to use this solution, but I won't be able to accept the answer as it does not answer the question :/ but your solution is great for my problem!

Comment: Hahah yes :P sorry. However Wezly, just noticed a problem. as you can see in my code only the div with the tel: and sms: shall appear on the phone. but not on the desktop... any ideas?

Comment: add some more classes to your media query, i will update my answer to explain.

Comment: You mean add it to my question mate?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that in CSS because CSS does not affect DOM tree.

Instead, you could use some jQuery script to clone your div.

Here is a demo from jQuery docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>clone demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Hello</b><p>, how are you?</p>

<script>
$( "b" ).clone().prependTo( "p" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: This would add the <b> tags also? op just wanted content i think?

Comment: Plus the example given was two `div` elements

Comment: Gee, whats wrong with you? It just shows the concept. I put it here just because SO rules say that you should not post just a link as an answer but instead add some code that shows the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("div2").appendChild(
    document.getElementById('"div1"')
  );
```